# Which .NET Azure Service Bus library should I use for queues?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Microsoft has two Azure Service Bus packages on NuGet:

- [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/)

  > Use this for Microsoft Azure Service Bus Queues, Topics, EventHub and Relay backend operations.
- [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/)

  > This is the next generation Azure Service Bus .NET Standard client library that focuses on queues & topics

At first it sounds like you should pick `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`. The package description is literally a command to "use this" for queues. But `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` calls itself "the next generation."

[The GitHub project for `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) doesn't exactly help matters, either: The README links to [code samples that use `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/) (as of February 2020).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the blog post [The future of Azure Service Bus .NET SDK](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/the-future-of-asb-dotnet-sdk)
there are now three SDKs for Service Bus:

- WindowsAzure.ServiceBus
- Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus
- Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, which is the newest one, was recently released and is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/). There are some [official samples available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azuremessagingservicebus-samples/) for it. Therefore I recommend using that SDK unless you find there is some critical functionality you need missing in it. To report bugs and request new functionality go to the [Azure SDK GitHub home](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I edited my answer accordingly. I wanted to include the names so that it'll be easy for Google skimmers to get in and get out. If you edit to include the names in yours, I'm good with accepting yours instead if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For others having the same issue (which SDK to choose),
this MSDN overview has comparisons + samples in all 3 SDKs + a bunch of useful links. Took me AGES to find, but really useful (along with the background story in Enricos blogpost).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2