# Which Azure ServiceBus SDK should be used?

Tags: sdk, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

At the time of this post there are two Azure Service bus SDKs sitting within [sdk/servicebus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus_5.1.0/sdk/servicebus):

- [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus_5.1.0/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus)
- [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.0.0/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus)

They have both been updated very recently (past week).

This [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) (written two weeks ago) states;

> This quickstart uses the new `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package. For a
> quickstart that uses the old `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package, see ....

Where as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk) document (also written two weeks ago) says;

> There are two supported Azure Service Bus .NET SDKs. Their APIs are
> similar, and it can be confusing which one to choose. Refer to the
> following table to help guide your decision. We suggest using the
> `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` SDK as It's more modern, performant, and is
> cross-platform compatible. Additionally, it supports AMQP over
> WebSockets and is part of the Azure .NET SDK collection of open-source
> projects.

This document goes on to mention `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` as newer and (yet another SDK) `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` as older. It does not mention `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` at all.

Does anyone have any advice on which SDK should be used for a new .NET Core 5.0 project?

(I have already reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283148/which-net-azure-service-bus-library-should-i-use-for-queues) which has not helped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For projects that have no dependency on the older packages, use Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. For everything else, look at the dependencies. For example, Azure Functions cannot use the latest package today. It will likely be addressed in the future just not ATM. I wrote a [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/the-future-of-asb-dotnet-sdk) awhile ago about these 3 packages. May (or may not) help you with your question.

Comment: Thanks @Sean-Feldman. I have read many of your posts, this one is exactly the information that I was looking for, and whilst I'm all for pushing forward, I agree that this is a mess right now. The documentation needs to make this update clearer.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. Eventually it will be sorted out. The intention is good and the way the SDK will be evolved in a long term will benefit customers.

Comment: Hey @SeanFeldman. Just wanted to say thank you so much for keeping the community informed and aware of these sort of things through blog posts and StackOverflow answer.